# Why arcpy.ListRasters() returns three lists?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, list

My folder has three TIFFs.

[image]

But when I use arcpy.ListRasters, it gives three lists that contain nine TIFFs.
Why it doesn't give one list containing three TIFFs?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/04.crash/t1"
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*","TIF")
for raster in rasters:
    print(rasters)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're printing raster**S** -- the variable from your `ListRasters`.
You want to just print `raster` (no s). Right now you're printing the list 3 times.